# CGDataProviderCopyData and EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios7, exc-bad-access, xcode5

I've imported my old Xcode3 project into Xcode5 and I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on following line:

```
pixelData =
 (NSData*) GDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(picture.image.CGImage))
```

Anyone has an idea what has changed?

it happens on iOS7. On iOS5 and iOS6 it works fine.

Comment: You might check if any of the objects involved is `nil`. Please add assertions and NSLogs.

Comment: picture.image.CGImage is not nil.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this:

```
CFMutableDataRef m_DataRef = CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0, CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(picture.image.CGImage))));
```

instead of this:

```
pixelData = (NSData*) GDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(picture.image.CGImage));
```

Check this:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/108072-exc_bad_access-in-ios-6-but-not-in-ios-5.html

Comment: CFMutableDataRef m_DataRef = CFDataCreateMutableCopy... still gives the same error. I've double checked picture.image.CGImage is not nil

Comment: And did you change UInt8 *m_PixelBuf=(UInt8 *)CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(m_DataRef);" as well?

Comment: OK I did like that:         

UInt8 * pixelDataNew=(UInt8 * )CFDataGetMutableBytePtr(CFDataCreateMutableCopy(0, 0, CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(picture.image.CGImage)))); 

pixelData = (NSData*)pixelDataNew;
     
and it doesn't give me an error, 
    
but how I can read bytes of the image now?     
char *pixelBytes = (char *)[pixelData bytes];
     
gives me an error.

Comment: Sorry I don't know if you can get NSData from UInt8 that easy by casting, I suggest to dig more in google to find better way, you can start from the Link I have already attached in my answer.